# Can I use "due to" as a noun modifier?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

> Low blood pressure due to dehydration can be treated by hydration.

I made this sentence, but the main point is, can I use "due to" as a noun (low blood pressure) modifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merriam-Webster defines *due to*:

> preposition

> as a result of : BECAUSE OF

The modifier of *pressure* is the preposition phrase *due to dehydration*.